# Finding modulo inverse if gcd is not 1

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have to find
$$\frac{p^e-1}{p-1} \bmod 1000000007,$$
where $p$ is a prime number. If $\gcd(p-1,1000000007)$ is not $1$, since  modular inverse of $p-1$ is not defined. Also, (p^e-1) is divisible by (p-1) (sum of a Geometric Progression). Also I can't find (p^e-1) since p,e<=10^18. So how do I find (p^e-1)/(p-1) mod 1000000007

Comment: If $(a,b)$ is not equal to $1$, then the modular inverse of $a$ modulo $b$ does not exist.

Comment: Where did you encounter this question? The reason I'm asking is that a certain programming contest site often want the answers given modulo an integer that is a power of ten plus a small number. And many users are strongly against allowing questions desgined to help askers do well in such contests. So I need to know.

Comment: www.spoj.com/problems/FACTMULP .

Comment: (p^e-1)%(p-1) =0 but I can't perform the division since p and e are <= 10^18

Answer (score 1):

If an element $a$ in the ring of integers mod $n$ is invertible, $\gcd(a,n)$ must be $1$. This is because the gcd must divide any linear combination of $a$ and $n$, and invertibility of $a$ mod $n$ implies that there is a linear combination that is equal to $1$.

As you noted, given prime $q$, if $\gcd(p-1,q) > 1$, then $p-1 = q$ and you want to find integer $k$ and $x \in [0..q)$ such that $qk = \frac{p^e-1}{q} - x$. That is easy; just manipulate the equation and take some modulo to remove $k$.

Comment: I have edited the ques. Actually I want to know how do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Maroof: I have edited my answer to give you a hint.